# Spanish bibliography overleaf

Tags: bibliographies, languages, overleaf

I am having so many troubles to find the way in which my bibliography can be written in spanish. Thus, without *in*, nor Edited by, but *y* and *Editado por*. I have tried this way and it does not work:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage[rflt]{floatflt}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Packages

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[spanish]{babel}

\usepackage[fixlanguage]{babelbib}



\usepackage{varioref}

\usepackage{achicago}                            

\usepackage{setspace}                 

\usepackage[lmargin=2.54cm,rmargin=2.54cm,top=2.54cm,bottom=2.54cm,right=70pt,includefoot]{geometry}


\usepackage{graphicx}               
\usepackage{wrapfig}              

\usepackage[bottom, marginal]{footmisc}
\usepackage{etoolbox}                  

\usepackage{datetime}                  



\usepackage[hidelinks,draft=false]{hyperref}       

\usepackage[medium, compact]{titlesec}  

\usepackage{nameref}                   
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}


\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\MakeUppercase{\chaptername\ \thechapter.\ #1}}{}}

\usepackage{chngcntr}                  

\usepackage{comment}                  
\usepackage{float}                     

\usepackage{afterpage}                 

\usepackage{tocloft}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{url}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% anexo


\usepackage{appendix}      %paquete para añadir anexos
\renewcommand{\appendixname}{Anexo}
\renewcommand{\appendixtocname}{Anexo I: Definiciones de Inclusión}
\renewcommand{\appendixpagename}{Anexo}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Style

%\usepackage{tgpagella}
%\usepackage{tgschola}


\fancyhead[]{}

\renewcommand{\headrule}{\vbox to 0pt{\hbox
to \headwidth{\dotfill}\vss}}

 
\titleformat{\section}
  {\singlespacing\normalfont\rmfamily\LARGE}
  {\thesection}{1em}{}
 \titlespacing*{\section}{0em}{3ex}{1ex}
  
  
\titleformat{\subsection}
  {\singlespacing\normalfont\rmfamily\Large}
  {\thesubsection}{1em}{}
 \titlespacing*{\subsection}{0em}{3ex}{1ex}


\titleformat{\subsubsection}
  {\singlespacing\normalfont\rmfamily\Large}
  {\thesubsubsection}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\subsubsection}{0em}{3ex}{1ex}


\titleformat{\paragraph}
  {\singlespacing\normalfont\rmfamily\slshape}
  {\thesection}{0.5em}{}
\titlespacing*{\paragraph}{0em}{4ex}{0ex}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\AtBeginDocument{\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\thispagestyle{empty}}} 



%%%TOC

\renewcommand{\contentsname}{\rmfamily Índice}                        

\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\Huge}

\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\rmfamily}{\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cftsecfont}{\rmfamily}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsecfont}{\rmfamily}

\renewcommand{\cftchappagefont}{\rmfamily}
\renewcommand{\cftsecpagefont}{\rmfamily}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsecpagefont}{\rmfamily}




%%%Bibliography

\apptocmd{\thebibliography}{\setlength{\itemsep}{15pt}}{}{}             
\makeatletter
\AtBeginEnvironment{thebibliography}{%         
   \clubpenalty10000
   \@clubpenalty \clubpenalty
   \widowpenalty10000}
\makeatother

%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Magic commands


 %Split the ff, fi...
\input{glyphtounicode}

\pdfglyphtounicode{f_f}{FB00}
\pdfglyphtounicode{f_f_i}{FB03}
\pdfglyphtounicode{f_f_l}{FB04}
\pdfglyphtounicode{f_i}{FB01}

\pdfgentounicode=1

\urlstyle{sf}                                  

\counterwithout{footnote}{chapter}              

\interfootnotelinepenalty=10000                  

\newcommand\blankpage{%                       
    \null
    \thispagestyle{empty}%
    \addtocounter{page}{-1}%
    \newpage}


\frenchspacing                                        


\setlength\parindent{1cm}                             


%%%%%%%%%%%%% Environments

\newenvironment{QTE}
    {\begin{center}
    \setstretch{1.2}
    \begin{quote}
    \begin{samepage}
    }
    {
    \end{samepage}
    \end{quote}
    \setstretch{2.0}
    \end{center}
    }


 
\newenvironment{FGR}
    {\begin{center}
    }
    {
    \bigskip
    \end{center}
    }



%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%




\setlength{\headheight}{51.60004pt}

\begin{document}
\sloppy
\onehalfspace
\urlstyle{same}                     

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% TITLEPAGE

\input{titulo.tex}
\pagebreak

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%TOC

\pagebreak
\setstretch{1.2}

\tableofcontents{\thispagestyle{empty}}
\pagestyle{plain}

\afterpage{\blankpage}
\pagebreak

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%PRETEXT
\pagenumbering{roman}

\input{cap0agradecimientos.tex}

\afterpage{\blankpage}
\pagebreak


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%STYLE OF PAGE
\thispagestyle{empty}
\fancyhead[]{}





%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%TEXTFILES%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setstretch{2.0} %doublespace
\setcounter{page}{1}
\input{cap1.tex}

\input{cap2.tex}

\input{cap3.tex}

\input{cap4}

\input{cap5}

\input{cap6}

\input{cap7}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%REFERENCES%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\newpage

\bibliographystyle{achicago}


\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliografía}

\singlespacing

\fancypagestyle{plain}{% 
     \fancyhf{} % clear all header and footer fields 
     \fancyhead[R]{} % except the right top corner 
     \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % remove line between header and main text
}

\nocite{*} 


\pagestyle{plain}

\bibliography{sample}

\end{document}

Can anyone help, please??? Thanks in advance. By the way, I am compalying with pdflatex
```

Comment: even if I comment out the `&&` lines that generate errors I can not run the example as it gives the error `! Undefined control sequence. l.15 \apptocmd` can you edit the example so that it shows the problem?

Comment: David Carlisle, thank you so much for your comment. I have included the comments I have deleted previously.. Maybe now it is easer